# What permissions are required for creating WMI Instances (such as with InstrumentationManager.Publish)?

Tags: .net, windows, permissions, wmi

The WMI namespaces/class has already been installed in WMI via InstallUtil / MOF. Adding new namespaces and classes is expected to be done in an elevated context.

However, code that publishes a WMI instance via [`InstrumentationManager.Publish`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.instrumentation.instrumentationmanager.publish(v=vs.110).aspx) throws an exception when running under a 'standard' domain account. The instance is successfully published when running under/as Administrator.

- *What is the (smallest) set of permissions required to allow WMI instance creation (via Publish) and later management?*

  - How could this be determined via observable logs / events? (The exception messages is generic and 'not useful' to determine the particular problem.)
- What is 'an easy' way to set up such permissions when the installer uses `DefaultManagementInstaller` / `WMIManagementInstaller`?

Comment: Probably 'Provider Write' in the respective namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/namespace-access-rights-constants .. so much digging for these 'were at one time working' things :}

Comment: Nope, something more than that.. Authenticated Users already have 'Provider Write' which is more permissive than 'Partial Write'.